Optional sampling theorem, $S\le T$ vs $S\le T$ a.s.
I have a question about the proof of the optional sampling theorem. It is from Jacod and Protters "Probability essentials". The proof uses that $S\le T$ a.s., but from what I see, they use a result that requires that $S\le T$ surely. I will show the details.
First note that they have this result:

From what I see, this requires that $S\le T$ surely? We are not under expectation here.
Then they have the optional sampling theorem:

Note, this book is in discrete time. Is the result wrong as it stand?, or can it be fixed? Do they have to assume $S\le T$ surely? Or can it be fixed? Note this is in discrete time, so they have not talked about the "usual conditions". But if we in fact had that $\mathcal{F}_0$ contained all the null-events it would hold? Is this what must be done?

Note that there is also an "a.s." in the conclusion of the theorem, although the proof seems to finish without this caveat. So you just apply the proof to the stopping time $T'=\max\{S,T\}$ to get $\mathbb E(X_{T'}\mid \mathcal F_S)=X_S$, and since $\mathbb E(X_{T}\mid \mathcal F_S)=\mathbb E(X_{T'}\mid \mathcal F_S)$ a.s., the result follows.

Cool trick, thanks!
